# Руководство пользователя по компилятору C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Я начинаю учится языку С++. У меня на компьютере стоит Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition. Но я не умею им пользоваться.

Посоветуйте любой другой проверенный компилятор или дайте инструктаж по Visual.

Comment: Тема про компиляторы уже есть.

Comment: Если я делаю что то не по правилам извените 
Я новичок
Лучше дайте ссылку

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/3592/ide-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-c-%D0%B8-c
Это тема про IDE. Там целый список на выбор. Насчет студии - рекомендую 2010 поставить и не понимаю, в чем проблема с ней. Нужен более конкретный вопрос. Чтобы запускать программу там наверху есть стрелочка зеленая. Это единственная догадка, что может быть не так.

Comment: Я раньше учился программиронию с С# там было проще Notepad ++
и компиляция через .Net 
Я учусь на первом курсе там нам дают Fortran там Compaq Visual Fortran еще проще но с ++ я никогда не сталкивался.

Comment: Так а где вопрос то конкретный?

Comment: Посоветуйте любой другой проверенный компилятор или дайте инструктаж по Visual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучший ресурс по компилятору MSVC и вообще по Visual Studio - это MSDN, потому что Microsoft - производитель этих продуктов. Если вы только начинаете ими пользоваться, то эта ссылка будет полезна: [Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ee329551.aspx).

Конкретно работа с собственно компилятором и компоновщиком описана здесь: [Образец построения C/C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/91621w01.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

[gcc (GNU Compiler collection)](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu) - хороший компилятор. Там же можно скачать отладчик - gdb. А для начала IDE лучше вообще не использовать, можно выбрать хороший текстовый редактор, например, [VIM.](http://www.vim.org) Если будут вопросы, по началу могу помочь.

**Добавление.**

Для того, чтобы выполнить компиляцию нужно в командной строке ввести:

```
gcc имя_файла_с_исходным_кодом -o имя_исполняемого_файла -lg++
```

`имя_исполняемого_файла` - это тот файл, который создаст компилятор в результате своей работы (его имя можно не указывать, тогда по умолчанию компилятор создаст файл a.out).
-lg++ - это привязка компилятора к библиотеке C++. Для обучения этого достаточно, но на будущее лучше для всего писать make файлы.

Comment: А как вы смотрите на использование Notepad++ ?

Comment: Notepad++ - хороший редактор.Но у Vim больше возможностей, из него можно сделать практически полноценную IDE, в которой будет только то, что нужно Вам.

Comment: Никита, спасибо! Не поленюсь - скачаю.
IDE - это интегрированная среда?

Comment: Да, IDE - Integrated Development Environment, интегрированная среда разработки.

Comment: Насчет редактора, посмотрите на Emacs. По сути это среда разработки с кучей возможностей для самостоятельного расширения (если это интересно).

Answer (score 1):

В чем конкретно проблема ? Вы не можете создавать новый проект, пользоваться отладчиком или писать коды программ? Если туговато с заходом в проект, могу посоветовать пошаговый алгоритм:

1. Start -> Visual Studio;
2. File -> New Project;
3. Visual C++ -> Win32 -> Win32 Concole Application;
4. Дать имя проекту (Enter name);
5. OK -> Next -> Empty Project -> Finish;
6. View -> Solution Explorer -> Sourse Files;
7. Sourse Files(правый клик) -> Add -> New Item;
8. Name -> Enter name -> Add;
9. Здесь писать код.

Дальше, думаю, сами справитесь. ))

Comment: Спасибо, уже разобрался. )
Как слышал на сайте, колбасу разрезать и то труднее. )

Answer (score 0):

- [Ресурсы по Visual Studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(MSDNSTART)&rd=true)
- [Общие форумы по Visual Studio](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/category/visualstudio,vsarch,vsdbg,vstest,vstfs,vsdata,vsappdev,visualbasic,visualcsharp,visualc)
- [Видео ресурсы по Visual Studio](http://www.techdays.ru/Category.aspx?Tag=Visual%2bStudio)

Другие компиляторы

- [Gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/)
- [MinGW](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/)

Comment: Обязательно пройду по всем ссылкам!

Answer (score 0):

Все очень просто. Не знаете чего-либо - покупаете и/или скачиваете книжку, читаете ее и изучаете + гуглите интернет. Кроме VS можно порекомендовать Intel C++. Но он платный, в отличие от VS Express.